# Formulation for making a binding choice in an online application

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a formulation that clearly indicates that a binding choice is made by pressing a button. The expression is written on a Button, so it has to be concise.

I currently use "Select X bindingly", which sounds awful.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could opt for "Permanently select X"; [*permanent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permanent) sounds more natural than *binding* in this case.

However (but this is more of a UX answer than an English answer), consider other alternatives to make sure the users realize they make a binding choice, such as a longer sentence just above the button (maybe explaining *why* the choice is binding), or a similarly worded confirmation popup.

Answer (score 0):

How about a button saying "Commit!" (I agree with Glorfindel, though, that there should be some kind of accompanying clarification.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something that will catch the reader's attention and trigger their legal reflexes, so that they understand that it is serious. For example, **"Sign the contract"** would make anyone pause and think before clicking.

If it isn't a contract, but a formal promise to do something, you could use the verb **"Pledge"** (especially if their lives, fortunes and sacred honor are on the line).